# Как создать сборку компонента на Vuejs, отдельного от основной сборки проета

Tags: vue.js, webpack, сборка

В моём проекте на Vuejs есть 3 компонента:

- Шапка
- Меню
- Контент

Все они собираются в одну сборку проекта.
Но я хочу, чтобы в неё еще собиралась отдельная сборка исключительно шапки. Хочу ее использовать по запросу к серверу этого приложения, на отдельном проекте.
Webpack позволяет это делать? Или есть другие способы это реализовать?[image: Шапка в моем проекте и стороннем]

Comment: почитайте про микрофронтенды, возможно это то, что вам нужно